# How to remove -(desk) sign when Save Contact number in Database From Phonbook Contact in Android?

Tags: android

I have some like strange confusion about like......i have an listView which is contain List of dvice's phonbook contacts and check box .....when any user check the checkBox at that time that contact number will save in SQLite database, But in database number is saved like below,

1-555-521-5556

And i want to save this record as simple as a  string like

15555215556

i want to remove - (desk) sign from the record that will save in databse...
Have somebudy have any idea to achieve this please tell to me.....thanks

Comment: I understand you're new here, but you should accept the answer that best suits your needs by clicking the checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take the phone number and put it into a string.  For example:

```
String phoneNum = // Number
```

Then just perform:

```
phoneNum.replace("-", "");
```

This will remove all "-" found in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just use String replace function..

```
"15555215556".replace("-", "");
```

it is just replace the - symbol .